# .text section of Linux dynamically shared libraries

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, objdump

I do not know whether I am asking a right question or not, but, When I get "objdump -d" from a .so Linux shared library and compare it with the corresponding package of that library, it seems that .text section does not exactly reflect the whole code written in the package. Is it right? If so, how can I know which .c and .h files are directly represented in .text section of an ELF file?

Answer (score 1):

`.text` is an assembly directive, it's unlikely that a developer wrote that, on the other hand it's likely to be something that was added by the compiler, `gcc` usually translate the code in `assembly` before compiling it.

to list the available sections in a compiled object you can use

```
readelf -S a.out
```

to disassemble just the `.text` section

```
objdump -d -j .text a.out
```

It's hard to say if this is something useful or not, at least in your specific case, but 1 thing it's for sure, to learn how to use this tools and how to debug your compiled object, you should learn `assembly` first, at least for your target.